# Bootstrap confirmation (remove click function ?)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started to study bootstrap and I'd like to ask a question about it.

I'm using "bootstrap confirmation" referenced with URL below. 
https://github.com/mistic100/Bootstrap-Confirmation/blob/master/example/index.html

I'm trying to use custom button of bootstrap confirmation
and i have a click function for this button as well.

but the problem is when i clicked the button it automatically show confirm box.
I wanted to show it when i call the function,

`$("#button_id").confirmation("show");`

as before I show confirm box i have to check the validation and get the result first...

Is there any way to do it? ..

ex)

```
$("#button_id").confirmation({
          rootSelector: '',
          container: 'body',
          buttons: [
            {
              class: 'class',
              value: 'YES',
              label: 'YES',
              onClick:function(){
              }
            }
          ]
        });
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a fiddle

Comment: @Aman Arora http://jsfiddle.net/pj9acmkd/2/ here i tried but after doing one time (after i call confirmation function) it will be automatically popped up when i click the button. am i misunderstanding the concept of this confirmation function  ? it can not control the time that I want to show with .confirmation("show") function ?

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle.
Just a General note, since you are new at bootstrap. You can have bootstrap functionality using attributes in HTML, or through JS.

In the Fiidle you provided, since you were using data-toggle="confirmation" data-popout="true", the Confirmation was appearing.

I'm gonna answer below, let me know on the answer if you have any queries

Comment: @Aman Arora Thank you for your answer. I think it works in same way...? After initialization, if i click again it will be popped regardless of  result of prompt. i guess in confirmation js file, it gets onclick event and shows confirmation automatically if it's initialized.  so it works with my onclick event at the same time. Am i correct? :<.. do you have any ideas to solve this ?

Comment: I've just found trigger manual option .... !!...omg

Comment: good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button id="bt1" class="btn btn-default" >Confirmation 1</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#bt1").click(function() {
  var test = prompt("test");
     if( test == "test"  )
   {
     $('#bt1').confirmation("show");
   }
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function validate() {
    return true;
}

$('#id').click( function() {
    var valid = validate();
    if(valid) {
        $('#id').modal('show');
    }
});
```